# Changing image of a skspritenode()

Tags: image, swift, sprite-kit

This is how I add my player's texture/image:

```
Player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"player8")
```

How do I change the players texture/image without adding or deleting spritenodes?

Answer (score 20):

You assign a different [texture](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKSpriteNode/texture):

```
player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"player8")
```

Sometime later:

```
player.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"player123")
```

Hint: it is bad style to begin variable, property and method names with an uppercase character as it makes them appear to be classes.