# Changing texture for subclass of SKSpriteNode?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sktexture

The `update` function in the class below, which is a subclass of SKSpriteNode, is supposed to change the texture of the class. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460191/changing-image-of-a-skspritenode), updating the `texture` property is sufficient for changing a SKSpriteNode's texture. However, this code doesn't work.

Any ideas why?

```
class CharacterNode: SKSpriteNode {       
    let spriteSize = CGSize(width: 70, height: 100)

    var level = 0

    init(level: Int) {
        self.level = level
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.clear, size: spriteSize)
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    func update(level: Int) {
        self.level = level            
        self.texture = textureForLevel(level: level)
    }


    func textureForLevel(level: Int) -> SKTexture {
        return SKTexture(imageNamed: "TestTexture")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works well. In fact this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460191/changing-image-of-a-skspritenode) is correct.

About `SKSpriteNode` subclass, the `update` method is a new custom function added by you, because the instance method [update(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skscene/1519802-update) is valid only for `SKScene` class, this just to say that this function is not performed if it is not called explicitly.

To make a test about your class you can change your code as below( I've changed only `textureForLevel` method only to make this example):

```
class CharacterNode: SKSpriteNode {
    let spriteSize = CGSize(width: 70, height: 100)
    var level = 0
    init(level: Int) {
        self.level = level
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.clear, size: spriteSize)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func update(level: Int) {
        self.level = level
        self.texture = textureForLevel(level: level)
    }
    func textureForLevel(level: Int) -> SKTexture {
        if level == 3 {
            return SKTexture(imageNamed: "TestTexture3.jpg")
        }
        return SKTexture(imageNamed: "TestTexture.jpg")
    }
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let characterNode = CharacterNode(level:2)
        characterNode.update(level:2)
        addChild(characterNode)
        characterNode.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX,y:self.frame.midY)
        characterNode.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.0), completion: {
            characterNode.update(level:3)
        })
    }
}
```

As you can see when you launch `GameScene` a characterNode sprite will be shown in the center of the screen. After 2 seconds, the texture will change.

Comment: Hah, you're right. The code is fine. Just a bug in testing. :)